# Sitecore, prevent HTML cache for Redirect response

Tags: sitecore

I have a page that after 4 seconds must redirect to another URL (basically if a backend service takes too long to respond). I'm doing a 302 redirect but Sitecore is storing the response HTML and the next time I enter the page I get an "Object moved here" rendering.

How can I prevent HTML cache (server side cache, not browser cache) for redirect responses? I'm using a "return Redirect(url);" to make the redirect.

Thank you

Comment: did you try to set disableBrowserCaching to true on the site configuration to see if the issue is related to caching ?

Comment: Turned off HTML caching and the problem stopped occuring. And I'm not talking about browserCaching, I'm talking about Sitecore HTML caching (on the server side).

Comment: When you set disableBrowserCaching to false the entire page will be cached. That's why setting this to true fixed your issue.

Comment: Setting to true didn't solve my issue, the site was already set to true. What solved my issue was disabling HTML cache on server side which I don't want to do, because I want to cache 200 responses (not 302 responses which are temporary).

Comment: Do you have a processor which perform the URL rewrite or redirect where you cache other Status code? For example 200, 404 and so on?

Comment: No. I don't, no custom logic.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML cache stores the entire HTML output. If there is a need to vary the output based on some custom logic then a customization needs to be made in order for this to work correctly. There are several different options depending on your need. I had this exact same issue at some point i used option 2 but the correct solution really depends on your application.

1. Remove the timeout so the HTML is always the same
2. Call the backend service client side or create a separate service in Sitecore which calls the backend service to avoid it getting include in the output cache
3. Create a custom CacheKey pipeline so a different cache key is
   generate in case the backend service takes too long, see [here](https://laubplusco.net/modifying-cache-keys-webcontrols-sitecore/)

Answer (score 0):

There are issues with 302 with certain browsers. use the newer 307 "Temporary Redirect"

You can prevent caching by setting headeres:

```
"Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
"Pragma: no-cache"
"Expires: 0"
```